# Random values seem to be not really random?

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying to make a simple bacteria-killing game using WinForm in C#, but the bacteria  (I am using `Panel` for the time being) doesn't seem to move around at random.

Specifically, the problem I am having is, the bacteria tries to move towards the upper left corner and move around there only. Ideally, the bacteria needs to move around the rectangle range evenly, but I am not sure how to achieve that.
Look at the *gif* file below.

[image]

As you can see the red `Panel` moves around the upper left corner only. How can I get it to move everywhere evenly and randomly?

Here is my code:

```
private Panel _pnlBacteria;     //Panel representing a piece of bacteria
private Random r = new Random();  //For randomly-generated values
private int _prevX;        //Stores the previous X location
private int _prevY;        //Stores the previous Y location

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _pnlBacteria = new Panel();
    /* Get more property assignments to this._pnlBacteria (omitted) */

    //Bacteria's start position is also randomly selected
    _prevX = r.Next(50, 300);
    _prevY = r.Next(50, 500);
}

//Timer runs every 100 seconds changing the location of the bacteria
private void TmrMoveBacteria_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x, y;
    //Get random values for X and Y based on where the bacteria was previously
    //and move randomly within ±10 range. Also it cannot go off the screen.
    do 
    {       
        x = r.Next(_prevX - 10, _prevX + 10);
        y = r.Next(_prevY - 10, _prevY + 10);
    } 
    while ((y <= 0) || (y >= 500) || (x <= 0) || (x >= 300));

    //Save the new location to be used in the next Tick round as previous values
    _prevX = x;
    _prevY = y; 

    //Apply the actual location change to the bacteria panel
    _pnlBacteria.Top = y;
    _pnlBacteria.Left = x;
}
```

I tried changing the +10 to +12, leaving -10 as it is, but now this only made the bacteria move to the bottom right corner only. I am at a loss. 
Can anyone please help?

Comment: Random.Next(a,b) means a<=x<b. So I think b should be 11 here so the random to be balanced. Have you tried this?

Comment: I believe one problem is that you're moving it by a fixed amount relative to the previous coordinate. `prevX - 10` etc. Maybe change that `10` to a random value as well.

Comment: Also this Random class is a better random number generator. https://gist.github.com/sachintha81/a4613d09de6b5f9d6a1a99dbf46e2385

Comment: It seems to be moving around in a proper manner to me. The reason it is staying in one general location is because that's where it starts and it is not likely to move too far away. This is because the randomness should average out over a long period of time to about zero movement from the original location. (Not an expert on this kind of stuff, someone correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @SergeyProsin  Omg was this as simple as this? I changed the +10 to +11 and it started working as ideally... I tried +12, but not +11.  Thank you thank you for all

Comment: Hmm please check my answer. It is not going to behave as you expect with a max 10 range with your code as is.

Comment: Perhaps you should choose a random *direction* (and possibly any direction except the one that takes it back to the previous location) so that it's always moving forwards. You could also then choose a random *distance* to move in that direction, but the code would get slightly more complicated if you want the bacteria to have a constant speed.

Comment: Nice GIF, but still... it took me ~20 seconds to get this [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) with keywords "inclusive" / "exclusive", even though I've never used C# in my entire life. Looks like a trivial 10 -> 11 typo.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad You're more or less wrong. Einstein (yeah, Albert) showed that an the isotropic random walker on an unbounded field which has taken `n` steps will have moved, on average, to a distance proportion to `sqrt(n)` away from it's starting place. Now, different walkers will go in different directions so the net motion of a statistical population is zero, but the expectation for a single walker is to travel. Bounded fields, as here, make the problem much more complicated, of course.  Search terms: *drunkard's walk* and *random walk*.

Comment: @dmckee interesting, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A slightly different way to tackle this might be to choose a random **direction** and a random **distance** to travel in that direction. This will allow more movement over the form if we increase the maximum distance the bacteria can travel before changing direction.

We can also "weight" the randomness of the distance so that shorter distances are chosen more often. This will add more variety and randomness to the movement pattern, while still allowing a few long sprints to another location.

Here's an example that you can copy/paste into a new form project implementing this idea. You can play with the settings for `maxDistance` (the furthest distance allowed before changing direction) and `stepDistance` (the distance travelled on each iteration of the `Timer`). A smaller `stepDistance` will result in smoother, but slower movement. I've made it pretty small, so I've also decreased the `Interval` property of the `Timer` to speed it up.

You'll notice I also added a method to validate that the direction is valid, so that the bacteria doesn't run off the screen. I created an `enum` to represent directions, which made it easy to check for movement in a particular direction (i.e. if the enum value contains "North" and we're too close to the top, then it's an invalid direction - this covers "North", "NorthWest", and "Northeast" directions).

**Edit:** I moved the creation of the "weighted distances" list to the constructor, and modified it to select exponentially fewer items rather than linearly fewer items.

Hope it makes sense:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Program Settings and Controls
    private readonly Panel pnlBacteria;             // Panel representing a piece of bacteria
    private readonly Random random = new Random();  // For randomly-generated values
    private readonly Timer tmrMoveBacteria;         // Timer used for bacteria movement
    private readonly int bacteriaSize = 20;         // Stores the size for our bacteria
    private const int maxDistance = 50;             // The maximum number of moves allowed in the same direction.
    private const int stepDistance = 3;             // The distance to travel on each iteration of the timer. Smaller number is slower and smoother
    private readonly List<int> weightedDistances;   // Contains a weighted list of distances (lower numbers appear more often than higher ones)

    // Bacteria state variables
    private Direction direction;  // Stores the current direction bacteria is moving
    private int distance;         // Stores the distance remaining to travel in current direction

    // Represents possible directions for bacteria to move
    private enum Direction
    {
        North, NorthEast, East, SouthEast, South, SouthWest, West, NorthWest
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Initialize our weighted differences array so that 1 is  
        // chosen most often and maxDistance is chosen the least often
        weightedDistances = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < maxDistance; i++)
        {
            var weight = maxDistance / (i + 1);

            for (var j = 0; j <= weight; j++)
            {
                weightedDistances.Add(i + 1);
            }
        }

        // Give life to the bacteria
        pnlBacteria = new Panel
        {
            BackColor = Color.Red,
            Width = bacteriaSize,
            Height = bacteriaSize,
            Left = random.Next(0, ClientRectangle.Width - bacteriaSize),
            Top = random.Next(0, ClientRectangle.Height - bacteriaSize)
        };
        Controls.Add(pnlBacteria);

        // Start bacteria movement timer
        tmrMoveBacteria = new Timer {Interval = 10};
        tmrMoveBacteria.Tick += TmrMoveBacteria_Tick;
        tmrMoveBacteria.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the direction and distance fields to valid values based on the
    /// current bacteria position, direction, and remaining distance
    /// </summary>
    private void UpdateDirectionAndDistance()
    {
        // Get all directions
        var validDirections = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction)).Cast<Direction>();

        // Remove invalid directions (based on the bacteria position)
        if (pnlBacteria.Top < bacteriaSize) validDirections = 
            validDirections.Where(dir => !dir.ToString().Contains("North"));

        if (pnlBacteria.Right > ClientRectangle.Width - bacteriaSize) validDirections = 
            validDirections.Where(dir => !dir.ToString().Contains("East"));

        if (pnlBacteria.Left < bacteriaSize) validDirections = 
            validDirections.Where(dir => !dir.ToString().Contains("West"));

        if (pnlBacteria.Bottom > ClientRectangle.Height - bacteriaSize) validDirections = 
            validDirections.Where(dir => !dir.ToString().Contains("South"));

        // If we're supposed to keep on moving in the same 
        // direction and it's valid, then we can exit
        if (distance > 0 && validDirections.Contains(direction)) return;

        // If we got here, then we're setting a new direction and distance
        distance = weightedDistances[random.Next(weightedDistances.Count)];
        var directions = validDirections.Where(d => d != direction).ToList();
        direction = directions[random.Next(directions.Count)];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes on each iteration of the timer, and moves the bacteria
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void TmrMoveBacteria_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Ensure direction and distance are valid
        UpdateDirectionAndDistance();

        // Move the bacteria
        var dirStr = direction.ToString();
        if (dirStr.Contains("North")) pnlBacteria.Top -= stepDistance;
        if (dirStr.Contains("East")) pnlBacteria.Left += stepDistance;
        if (dirStr.Contains("South")) pnlBacteria.Top += stepDistance;
        if (dirStr.Contains("West")) pnlBacteria.Left -= stepDistance;

        distance--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

If you read the documentation of Random.next(int,int) you'll find the the lower bound is inclusive and the upper bound is exclusive, that's why -10 and +11 works.

Answer (score 1):

The left and right arguments of `r.Next` are inclusive and exclusive respectively.

```
x = r.Next(_prevX - 10, _prevX + 10);
y = r.Next(_prevY - 10, _prevY + 10);
```

So the probability space of this code is a 19x19 square off center of `(_prevX,_prevY)` to its upper left. This means displacement is more likely towards the upper left.

If we use 11s on the right, then the probability space is a 20x20 square centered at `(_prevX,_prevY)`. The bacteria will move more evenly. Its average displacement within its probability square is zero, so there's not a single favored direction. But **the diagonal directions will be favored since diagonal displacement is the greatest on average**. This may or may not be important depending on the situation.

If we use radius and direction [as explained by Rufus L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51794701/7675254), then we can generate a more "natural" circular probability space. That's why it's the preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the size of your panel.height - size of your square.height same for length instead of constants this way if the screen size changes your game will still work.

```
_prevX = r.Next(bateriaSize, this.Width-bacteriaSize); //this.Width Gets you the of form
_prevY = r.Next(bateriaSize, this.Height-bacteriaSize); //This.Height gets you the height of form
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are moving the object back and forth because the range is prev -+10;

```
 x = r.Next(_prevX - 10, _prevX + 10);
 y = r.Next(_prevY - 10, _prevY + 10);
```

you should add a direction flag for yval and xval, set it with certain probability p(less then 1/2) , when the flag is on go right/up, when its off go left/down ,

```
if (forwardx){
    x = r.Next(_prevX , _prevX + 10);
}
else {
     x = r.Next(_prevX - 10, _prevX );
}
if (forwardy){
    y = r.Next(_prevY , _prevY + 10);
}
else{
    y = r.Next(_prevY - 10 , _prevY );
}

forwardx = r.Next(10) == 1; //p = 0.1
forwardy = r.Next(10) == 1;
```

Good luck!